# How to detect a change in html element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have an alert-message element, which I would like to hide after 2 seconds. I have a javascript that runs after the page load, and it does hire any alerts appears when the page load.

However, there are alerts that shows up after the page load, and these alerts will stay on. How do I observe changes, i.e., if the alert-message element is visible again, to hide it after 2 seconds?

This the code I used to hide the first alert:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   var hide_delay = 4000;  // starting timeout before first message is hidden
   var hide_next = 800;   // time in mS to wait before hiding next message
   $(".alert-message").slideDown().each( function(index,el) {
      window.setTimeout( function(){
         $(el).slideUp();  // hide the message
      }, hide_delay + hide_next*index);
   });
```

Thank you.

Comment: There's not really an efficient way to do this. Is it not possible to modify the code which shows alerts?

Comment: The best way I can think of is constantly checking it with setInterval or setTimeout but that is a bad solution. The most optimal would be somehow hooking into these "alerts" you need to work with.

Comment: Hi Kris, it seems to be the right direction. Could you be more specific? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you might want a timer?  What you would want to do is, at the end of the function/code that displays the alert to the user, do something like this:

```
var timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
   // code here to hide the alert
}, 2000);
```

The number 2000 is in milliseconds and should mean that at roughly 2 seconds after the timer is created, the code would run in the anonymous function that would then hide the alert.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like the "DOMNodeInserted" event but this is not supported in IE. So you can use liveQuery to listen to DOM changes instead. Hopefully this is something that you're looking for.

[LiveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

You can then use it like this to listen to element changes:

```
$('#elementToListenTo').livequery(function(){
    // If $(this) element has been changed, perform things below.
    var timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
       // Perform a task after 2 seconds
        $(".alert-message").slideDown();
    },2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Fiddle idea: http://jsfiddle.net/ekr8v/4/

When you create an alert, you give it an ID and you create a timeout (see Eli Sand's code above) that will remove that ID after 2 seconds.

In the tutorial in my fiddle, I just used the Unix timestamp which I think would work just fine here.

Comment: You don't even need to give the element any unique properties.  If the element is created out of thin air in a function, you need only assign it to a variable and then you can refer to that variable within the anonymous function triggered by the timer.  Eg: `var elem = $('<div>some alert</div>');` then refer to `elem` within your timer like `$(elem).remove();`.